# AWS Route 53 > Error occured when creating/updating a record

Tags: amazon-web-services, mx-record, amazon-route53

I created a TXT record @.domain.com with TXT "v=spf1 a mx ~all" on AWS successfully. It didn't work with my post office config so I went to update it by removing the record name "@" and received error:

```
A record with the specified name already exists.
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: Tried to create resource record set [name='domain.com.', type='TXT'] but it already exists)
```

I thought it might because the record exists so I removed this record and tried to create a new record with the same TXT and received the same error.

I also tried to wait for more than 30 minutes then refreshed. It didn't help though.

Who knows what mistake did I make? Appreciate.

Comment: 1 - How did you update the records? Did you use a the GUI? Did you use a CLI?
2 - Not sure I understand, did you try to create a record for `@.domain.com` and then replace it with a record for `domain.com`?